# Svelte: Proper way to pass reactive prop in component constructor?

Tags: svelte

Given the minimal demo below, reactivity works as expected when using the `<Component/>` tag, but you lose the reactivity when using the component constructor:

**App.svelte**

```html
<script>
  import { onMount } from 'svelte';
  import Component from './Component.svelte';
  let component;
  let enabled = false;
  onMount(() => {
    new Component({
      target: component,
      props: { enabled },
    });
  });
</script>

<h1>Component</h1>
<form>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" bind:checked={enabled}> Enabled
  </label>
</form>
<hr>
<p>Using tag...</p>
<Component {enabled}/>
<hr>
<p>Using constructor...</p>
<div bind:this={component}></div>
```

**Component.svelte**

```html
<script>
  export let enabled = false;
</script>

{#if enabled}
<p>I'm enabled!</p>
{/if}
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/fc6617a72cd446028c30d6bf2e98990e)

What is considered the "best practice" way to pass the `enabled` prop to `Component.svelte` using the constructor such that it retains its reactivity?

Comment: Why are you using the constructor in the first place?

Comment: @H.B. I'm using it in a function that triggers when someone clicks on a button to load older posts. I will try to change the design so that I can avoid the constructor pattern (something like adding another property to limit how many items to extract from posts array).

Comment: @H.B. let's say I introduce a new prop called `postCount` with default value of 10, and when user clicks on "load older" I change the value to 20 -- will this cause the component to re-render all 20 posts or only append the next 10 posts to the existing 10?

Comment: That depends, among other things on how the relevant data is loaded.

Comment: @H.B. here's what I ended up with: `{#each posts.slice(postsLength - postCount, postsLength) as post}<Post .../>{/each}` (`postsLength` = `posts.length`). Whenever someone clicks "load more" I increment `postCount` by 10. This is working fine so far since I only have a few posts, but I was worried if I have thousands of posts it might be inefficient if it has to re-render all posts again every time `postCount` changes.

Comment: Svelte only does the bare minimum necessary. For existing posts it will do nothing, at least if you use a keyed each (see [`#each` docs](https://svelte.dev/docs/logic-blocks#each)) or only add items at the end. Doing things this way is the "intended" way.

Comment: Thanks, you have confirmed what I just witnessed in my latest [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/1d52f16fe3c84a3ba1bcf4b6ff7f5ee5) (crated before you posted your comment). Only new items are logged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Client-side component API](https://svelte.dev/docs/client-side-component-api) is what you need. For your use case you need `component.$set(props)`.

But reactivity in svelte is provided by compiler, so you still need to use a `$:`  statement to maintain reactivity of `enabled` state.

```html
<script>
  import { onMount } from 'svelte';
  import Component from './Component.svelte';
  let componentContainer;
  let component;
  let enabled = false;
  onMount(() => {
    component = new Component({
      target: componentContainer,
      props: { enabled },
    });
  });

  $: component?.$set({ enabled });
</script>
```

Comment: Awesome, this seems like the most concise solution so far. However, please see my comment to @H.B. above -- is it more efficient to add a new `postCount` prop to the existing tag or use this solution for this scenario (loading older posts when clicking a button)? I'm leaning towards adding `postCount` since using the constructor in addition to having the tag seems like redundant code.

Comment: I have decided to redesign the way I render the component, but since your solution did answer the original question I will accept it. Thanks.